# How do I get a list of application suggestions for a given file type in Qt5?

Tags: qt, user-interface, cross-platform, desktop-application, desktop-integration

**Background Information:** I'm building a small cross-desktop application using Qt5. I want to limit this application to only one specific task. Anything else should be delegated to other applications installed on the user's system. More concretely:

1. I want my application to be opened by other applications, such as image viewers, and be suggested in context menus (e.g. "Open with..").
2. I want my application to present the user with a list of applications he or she can use to continue working with the result. (e.g. image viewers' "open with" menu option).

As far as I can tell, input integration can not be implemented in a desktop agnostic way; i.e. I must install `.desktop` application files in XDG desktops or define appropriate keys under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications` in the windows registry before the desktop can suggest the applications to users.

**Question:** Since my application will be responsible for providing the user with a list of applications to open the output, does Qt offer anything I can use to limit the amount of platform-specific code I need to write and test?

I have already found many ways to get this information in a desktop-specific way (e.g. [Gnome](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GAppInfo.html), [KDE](https://api.kde.org/frameworks/kio/html/classKOpenWithDialog.html), or even processing [XDG directories](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-1.2.html) or [relevant windows registry entries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/shell/app-registration) directly) but my hope here is to limit the the amount of time I need to spend on each desktop.

Thank you for your time and apologies for the poor English.